# 8 bit 2d array in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a small problem in saving data in a array. I want to save data in the form 10001010 <- 8 bits in a 2d array containing 100 rows and 100 columns. what i do now is

```
a = rand(100,100);
a = a * 127; // <<- this is done to make it 8 bits
```

To confirm what i have done i did a imshow to display the image.

When a is multiplied by 127 most of the grayscale pixels has turned to white but before the multiplication step it showed a nice grayscale image.

a = rand(100,100);[image]  after a = a * 127;  [image]

Comment: Are you saying you want an array of integer values in the range 0->255?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 8-bit representation it's actually 0->255 since image intensities are unsigned. Matlab checks which class the image is when using imshow, if it's a double, the range 0->1 is expected. Hence you need to cast the image to uint8 after multiplying for it to show properly.

```
a = rand(100,100);
a = a*255;
a = uint8(a);
imshow(a);
```

Comment: are grayscale images unsigned 8 bit ?

Comment: There's really no point in a negative intensity, hence unsigned. But you can represent it in any way you want to I guess. This is how imshow will draw the image though, and what I think you were looking for.